# AudioSet and Tensorflow Understanding

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

With [AudioSet](https://research.google.com/audioset/index.html) released and providing a brand new area of research for those who do sound analysis for research, I've been really trying to dig deep these last few days on how to analyze and decode such data.

The data is given in .tfrecord files, heres a small snippet.

```
�^E^@^@^@^@^@^@C�bd
u
^[
^Hvideo_id^R^O

^KZZcwENgmOL0
^^
^Rstart_time_seconds^R^H^R^F
^D^@^@�C
^X
^Flabels^R^N^Z^L

�^B�^B�^B�^B�^B
^\
^Pend_time_seconds^R^H^R^F
^D^@^@�C^R�

�

^Oaudio_embedding^R�

�^A
�^A
�^A3�^] q^@�Z�r�����w���Q����.���^@�b�{m�^@P^@^S����,^]�x�����:^@����^@^@^Z0��^@]^Gr?v(^@^U^@��^EZ6�$
�^A
```

The example proto given is:

```
context: {
  feature: {
    key  : "video_id"
    value: {
      bytes_list: {
        value: [YouTube video id string]
      }
    }
  }
  feature: {
    key  : "start_time_seconds"
    value: {
      float_list: {
        value: 6.0
      }
    }
  }
  feature: {
    key  : "end_time_seconds"
    value: {
      float_list: {
        value: 16.0
      }
    }
  }
  feature: {
    key  : "labels"
      value: {
        int64_list: {
          value: [1, 522, 11, 172] # The meaning of the labels can be found here.
        }
      }
    }
}
feature_lists: {
  feature_list: {
    key  : "audio_embedding"
    value: {
      feature: {
        bytes_list: {
          value: [128 8bit quantized features]
        }
      }
      feature: {
        bytes_list: {
          value: [128 8bit quantized features]
        }
      }
    }
    ... # Repeated for every second of the segment
  }

}
```

My very direct question here - something that I can't seem to find good information on is - how do I convert cleanly between the two?

If I have a machine readable file, how to make it human readable, as well as the other way around.

I have found [this](https://github.com/jkschin/tf_code/blob/master/TFRecords%20Example/reader.py) which takes a tfrecord of a picture and converts it to a readable format... but I can't seem to get it to a form that works with AudioSet

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me, storing the features in feat_audio.  to plot them, convert them to an ndarray and reshape them accordingly.

```
audio_record = '/audioset_v1_embeddings/eval/_1.tfrecord'
vid_ids = []
labels = []
start_time_seconds = [] # in secondes
end_time_seconds = []
feat_audio = []
count = 0
for example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(audio_record):
    tf_example = tf.train.Example.FromString(example)
    #print(tf_example)
    vid_ids.append(tf_example.features.feature['video_id'].bytes_list.value[0].decode(encoding='UTF-8'))
    labels.append(tf_example.features.feature['labels'].int64_list.value)
    start_time_seconds.append(tf_example.features.feature['start_time_seconds'].float_list.value)
    end_time_seconds.append(tf_example.features.feature['end_time_seconds'].float_list.value)

    tf_seq_example = tf.train.SequenceExample.FromString(example)
    n_frames = len(tf_seq_example.feature_lists.feature_list['audio_embedding'].feature)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    rgb_frame = []
    audio_frame = []
    # iterate through frames
    for i in range(n_frames):
        audio_frame.append(tf.cast(tf.decode_raw(
                tf_seq_example.feature_lists.feature_list['audio_embedding'].feature[i].bytes_list.value[0],tf.uint8)
                       ,tf.float32).eval())

    sess.close()
    feat_audio.append([])

    feat_audio[count].append(audio_frame)
    count+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have done so far. The prepare_serialized_examples is from the youtube-8m starter [code](https://github.com/google/youtube-8m/blob/master/readers.py).
I hope that helps :)

```
import tensorflow as tf

feature_names = 'audio_embedding'

def prepare_serialized_examples(serialized_example, max_quantized_value=2, min_quantized_value=-2):

    contexts, features = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
        serialized_example,
        context_features={"video_id": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                          "labels": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)},
        sequence_features={'audio_embedding' : tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([10], dtype=tf.string)
    })

    decoded_features = tf.reshape(
    tf.cast(tf.decode_raw(features['audio_embedding'], tf.uint8), tf.float32),
    [-1, 128])

    return contexts, decoded_features


filename = '/audioset_v1_embeddings/bal_train/2a.tfrecord'
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=1)

reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    context, features = prepare_serialized_examples_(serialized_example)

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init_op)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    print(sess.run(features))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Ok. so we have contexts and features.. what are the types of these objects? how to print them in a way that is human readable?

Comment: @Zach that took longer than expected. Sorry about that. I have updated my answer. The decoding inside the `prepare_serialized_examples_` is used so that you read floats and not binary values.

As you probably already know your graph should run inside a session in order to be computed.

Comment: @jerpint Something got lost while pasting. I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

The AudioSet data is not a tensorflow.Example protobuf, like the image example you have linked. It's a **SequenceExample**.

I've not tested but you should be able to use the code you linked if you replace [`tf.parse_single_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_example) with [`tf.parse_single_sequence_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_sequence_example) (and replacing the field names).

Comment: Thank you  - this got me pretty far, however now 'features' returns a pointer, and trying to print this gives: TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got {'labels': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleSequenceExample/ParseSingleSequenceExample:1' shape=() dtype=int64>, 'start_time_seconds': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleSequenceExample/ParseSingleSequenceExample:2' shape=() dtype=float32>, 'video_id': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleSequenceExample/ParseSingleSequenceExample:3' shape=() dtype=string>, 'end_time_seconds': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleSequenceExample/ParseSingleSequenceExample:0' shape=() dtype=float32>}

Comment: That will return a dict of tensors. You can now use them in your computational graph, e.g. `one_video_id = sess.run(features['video_id'])`. Or start to batch them up with `tf.train.shuffle_batch`. More details on graph execution here: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#building_a_tensorflow_graph

Answer (score 0):

The [YouTube-8M](https://research.google.com/youtube8m/) [starter code](https://github.com/google/youtube-8m) should work with the AudioSet tfrecord files out of the box.

Comment: Of course - and i got it up and running... the problem is that i need to independently verify and run through data myself. And that includes visualizing and observing the actual data.